# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/cats-v-dog

Tags: python

I create some directories using os.mkdir

```
try:
#YOUR CODE GOES HERE
os.mkdir("/tmp/cats-v-dogs/")
os.mkdir("/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats")
os.mkdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/')
os.mkdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats')
os.mkdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs')
except OSError:
pass
```

I have list:
training =[dog1,dog2,...,dog100]
TRAINING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats/"
I want to copy a file from one directory to another one using trainig element:

```
for list1 in training:
copyfile(os.path.join(SOURCE,list1),TRAINING_DOGS_DIR)
```

After I run that loop this is the error I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/'
```

Some help or suggestion thanks/

Comment: your `except OSError:` is hiding your bug, remove that -- you might also want to use [`os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Answer (score 2):

The `try`-`except` block is what's hurting you here. `os.mkdir` is only able to make a single directory at a time depth-wise, so your second through fifth lines are all failing, but because you're catching the exception the error is correct.

Solution: replace all of the `os.mkdir` with `os.makedirs` which will create all of these without an issue. And get rid of the `try`-`except`! Those should only be used when you know exactly what you're catching.

Comment: yes, as well the shutil modeule as welll to copy the files, its work preaty well

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.makedirs` which includes an `exist_ok` parameter:

```
os.makedirs("/tmp/cats-v-dogs/", exist_ok=True)
```